# Unresponsive registrar

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

We have a domain that was bought through www.activeregistrar.com several years ago by a previous employee. All the domain does not expire until late next year, we have moved host and need to update nameservers, we would also like to transfer the domain over to a new registrar.

Problem being is we can not even find the login page, the previous employee is the only one with the login information(which we might be able to get), and the company is COMPLETELY unresponsive to support request, they completely ignore all emails. No phone number is listed, no address, nothing. So we have almost zero control over our domain.

What are  our options?

Comment: It may be time to break out the .44 auto-mag lawyer. Sometimes that is what it takes. We have answered questions like this on this site. Basically, you have to get their attention and make it a smart idea for them to be responsive to you in a highly proactive way. It takes making a business case and legal case and making sure that a high-level employee gets the message and not the lowest-level, lowest paid employee that must follow policies or get fired. It may be time to call the CEO. BTW- this works as long as you are nice. I have made friends that way!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search for that Registrar and domain name returns results for their [WHOIS contact info complete with telephone number and email address](http://www.whois.com/whois/activeregistrar.com), plus their [control panel login page](http://cp.activeregistrar.com/), so those are good places to start.

Before contacting them and pursuing this further, it would be smart to do a quick WHOIS lookup on 'your' domain to confirm you have the details correct. If the former employee bought the domain then it is possible they own it and not yourselves, though you would have a strong case if you planned to file a dispute with the Registrar.

Worst-case scenario is to file a dispute with ICANN but these are difficult and not really geared to resolve customer complaints. You would need to document your attempts to contact the Registrar and provide evidence that you represent the business, and that the Registrar is not merely slow to respond but is failing to take appropriate action to resolve the issue. This is complicated and since it's your business it probably means hiring a lawyer.

Make an extra effort to contact that former employee because that's the easiest way forward. After that send the Registrar a proper business letter (and obtain proof of delivery e.g. use FedEx or DHL or UPS, etc...) which conforms to their dispute resolution policy. Failing that, it's 'hire a lawyer to sort this out via ICANN'. Good luck.